# Do we still add $C$ when integrating and the result is an arbitrary function?

Tags: integration, soft-question

I apologize if this question sounds stupid.
I'm just bothered whether I should write

$$u(x,y) = f(x) + C$$

or just

$$u(x,y) = f(x)$$

For the solution of this problem:

$$\frac{\partial u(x,y)}{\partial y} = 0$$

I mean, isn't it sufficient enough if the solution is just  $f(x)$? since the constant is contained in an arbitrary function $f(x)$?

Comment: Indeed, the $C$ is redundant.

Comment: Probably a good idea either way, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When taking the antiderivative, anything that doesn't depend on the variable we're integrating over can be counted as a constant; for the space we're working with here, there's another variable that we can take into account when describing this "constant", so we can claim that any function in x is a valid potential solution.  In this case, instead of calling it $f(x)$, I'd probably name it something like $C_y(x)$, so it's obvious where it came from: it's the constant of integration we got when integrating $u$ with respect to $y$.

Comment: The OP's derivative is with respect to the independent variable $y$, not $x$, so $f(x)$ here is an arbitrary constant as far as $y$ is concerned. As Lewis MacRae pointed out in comments, there is no need to add an arbitrary constant $C$ to an arbitrary function.

Comment: You are right, I should read more carefully!